# 'services' object is not iterable Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm having a problem and here's my code please help. I did this because what I want is when an existing user login the details of the task done by the user automatically appears on the page because the database has multiple rows of every user I would like to display of particular user

This my view

```
def service(request,emp_id):
  u = User.objects.get(sys_id = emp_id)
  s = services.objects.get(email = emp_id)
  if request.method == 'POST':
      user_form = ServiceForm(data=request.POST)
      if user_form.is_valid():
          user_form.save()
      else:
          print(user_form.errors)
  else:
      user_form = ServiceForm()
  return render(request, 'service.html', {
      'user_form':user_form,'u':u,'s':s})
```

This is my model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
  sys_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
  email = models.EmailField(
      verbose_name='email address',
      max_length=255,
      unique=True,
  )
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
  address = models.TextField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
  DOB = models.DateField('Date of Birth', blank=True, null=True)
  DOJ = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
class services(models.Model):
  taskid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
  client = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
  project = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
  taskTime = models.DateField('Task Date', blank=True, null=True)
  hours = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  minutes = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  Description = models.TextField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
  email = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my html

```
{% for service in s %}  
<tr>  
    <td>{{ service.client }}</td>  
    <td>{{ service.project }}</td>  
    <td>{{ service.taskTime }}</td>  
    <td>{{ service.address }}</td>
    <td>{{ service.hours }}</td>
    <td>{{ service.minutes }}</td>
    <td>{{ service.Description }}</td>    
</tr>  
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to display only the details which belongs to particular user when user has logged in he should see only his services only. Table contains details of all users with multiple rows. so i would like to display only the details of single user with multiple rows.

Comment: `s` is a *single* service, so you can not `{% for ... %}` loop over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view, we see:

```
def service(request,emp_id):
  u = User.objects.get(sys_id = emp_id)
  s = services.objects.get(email = emp_id)
  if request.method == 'POST':
      user_form = ServiceForm(data=request.POST)
      if user_form.is_valid():
          user_form.save()
      else:
          print(user_form.errors)
  else:
      user_form = ServiceForm()
  return render(request, 'service.html', {
      'user_form':user_form,'u':u,'s':s})
```

So you `.get(..)` a `Service` this means that `s` is a `Service` object, *not* a *collection* of `Service` objects (i.e. a `QuerySet`). Therefore you can *not* iterate over it.

## Rendering a *single* `Service` object

You probably only want to render the `s` service, so you can replace the template with:

```
<tr>  
    <td>{{ s.client }}</td>  
    <td>{{ s.project }}</td>  
    <td>{{ s.taskTime }}</td>  
    <td>{{ s.address }}</td>
    <td>{{ s.hours }}</td>
    <td>{{ s.minutes }}</td>
    <td>{{ s.Description }}</td>    
</tr>
```

## Rendering a *collection* of `Service` objects

In case the `email` of the `Service` is not unique, you probably want to fetch *all* `Service` objects, you then should use `.filter(..)` instead of `.get(..)`:

```
def service(request,emp_id):
  u = User.objects.get(sys_id = emp_id)
  s = services.objects.filter(email = emp_id)
  if request.method == 'POST':
      user_form = ServiceForm(data=request.POST)
      if user_form.is_valid():
          user_form.save()
      else:
          print(user_form.errors)
  else:
      user_form = ServiceForm()
  return render(request, 'service.html', {
      'user_form':user_form,'u':u,'s':s})
```

In that case in the template you indeed have to iterate over the `service`s in `s` with `{% for service in s %}`.

> **Note**: it might be better to use more descriptive names like `services` instead of `s`, since right now the template is a bit "cryptic".